# Backslash in preprocessor definition in NMake .vcxproj

Tags: visual-studio, intellisense, preprocessor, nmake

In a NMake-based Visual Studio C++ project (.vcxproj) - autogenerated for LibreOffice project for IDE integration, I need to set a preprocessor definition (`SRCDIR`) which is a string including double quotes `"`. In the .vcxproj, it's done like this:

```
<NMakePreprocessorDefinitions>_WIN32_WINNT=0x0601;SRCDIR=&quot;\&quot;C:/lo/src/core\&quot;&quot;;$(NMakePreprocessorDefinitions)</NMakePreprocessorDefinitions>
```

so that the inner double quotes are properly escaped to use as a C string literal.

But trying to use `SRCDIR` in the C++ code, like in

```
const size_t nStrLen(std::strlen(SRCDIR));
```

I see this problem in the IntelliSense:

```
#define SRCDIR "\\"C:/lo/src/core\\""
Expands to: "\\"C:/lo/src/core\\""

user-defined literal operator not found
```

So the IntelliSense clearly escapes the backslash, breaking the string.

I need to mention that the VS project is not used to build the module (console make is used), so I cannot see if not only IntelliSense, but also the VS-based build is broken. But the question is: how to properly set a preprocessor define like this?